# Angular, data is shown in the console but not in the App

Tags: angular, console, rendering

So I am fetching data from the backend and it works since I can see it in the console [image]

But as you can see, it recognizes that the data is here but it's like there's some problem with rendering. Here's the relevant code

This is HTML part of the component

```
<h4>Details for Student: {{newStudent?.jmbag}}</h4>
<hr>
<span>JMBAG: </span>{{newStudent?.jmbag}}<br>
<span>ECTS: </span>{{newStudent?.ects}}
<div *ngIf="student?.pay">Tuition should be paid.</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let predmet of predmeti">
    <div>
      <a routerLink="/detailsPredmeti/{{newStudent?.jmbag}}">
        <span>{{predmet.naziv}} </span>
        <span>{{predmet.ects}} </span>
      </a>
      <span> - </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<a routerLink="/students"><h5>Povratak</h5></a>
```

And this is ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from '../student';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';
import { StudentDTO } from '../studentDTO';
import {PredmetiService} from "../predmeti.service";
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Predmet } from '../predmet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-predmeti',
  templateUrl: './student-predmeti.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-predmeti.component.css']
})
export class StudentPredmetiComponent implements OnInit {

  student: Student;
  newStudent: StudentDTO;
  predmeti: Predmet[];
  constructor(
    private studentService: StudentService,

    private predmetiService: PredmetiService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(() => {
      this.handleStudentDetails();
    })
  }

  handleStudentDetails() {
    const theStudentJmbag: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('jmbag')!;

    this.studentService.getStudentByJmbag(theStudentJmbag).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.newStudent = data;
        console.log('Student:', this.newStudent);
      }
    );

    this.predmetiService.getCoursesByStudentJmbag(theStudentJmbag).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.predmeti = data;
        console.log('Predmeti:', this.predmeti);
      }
    );
  }



}
```

I tried add ngif, so that it looks like this

```
<h4>Details for Student: {{newStudent?.jmbag}}</h4>
<hr>
<span>JMBAG: </span>{{newStudent?.jmbag}}<br>
<span>ECTS: </span>{{newStudent?.ects}}
<div *ngIf="student?.pay">Tuition should be paid.</div>
<hr>
<h5>Predmeti:</h5>
<div class="row">
  <table *ngIf="predmeti">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Naziv</th>
        <th>ECTS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let predmet of predmeti">
        <td>{{ predmet.naziv }}</td>
        <td>{{ predmet.ects }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<hr>
<a routerLink="/students"><h5>Povratak</h5></a>
```

But still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `predmet` object has `name` and `numberOfECTS` keyes, and not `naziv` and `ects` that you're trying to access.

Comment: No, that's how data is fetched from backend, but this is how it looks in Angular

export interface Predmet {
    naziv:string;
    ects: number;
}

I'm getting an error if I name them differently

Comment: Actually, you were right, names should match. Thanks a lot